# Mean over a sub-interval Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am using Python but since I am noob I can't figure out how to compute the average of a vector each, let's say, 100 elements in a larger for-loop.

My trial so far, which is not what I want is

```
import numpy as np

r = np.zeros(10000) # declare my vector

for i in range(0,2000): # start the loop
    r[i] = i**2 # some function to compute and save
    if (i%100 == 0): # each time I save 100 elements I want the mean
      av_r = np.mean(r)
      print(av_r)
```

My code do not work as I want because I would like to make the average of 100 elements only then pass to the other 100, compute the mean and go on.

I try to reduce the dimension of the vector and clean it into the if:

```
import numpy as np

r = np.zeros(100) # declare my vector

for i in range(0,2000): # start the loop
    r[i] = i**2 # some function to compute and save
    if (i%100 == 0): # each time I save 100 elements I want the mean
      av_r = np.mean(r)
      print(av_r)
      r = np.zeros(100)
```

naively, I thought you may save 100 elements, compute the average clean the vector and continue the calculation saving the other elements from 100+1 to 200+1 but it give me errors. In particular:

`IndexError: index 100 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 100`

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I suppose you want to do `r[i%100] = i**2`. But I can only suppose since "it give me errors" is just too broad. Please post stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error you probably have encountered is an arrays out of bounds (`IndexError: index 100 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 100`), because your index ranges from 0 to 1999 and you're doing

```
r[i] = i**2 # some function to compute and save
```

on a 100-sized array.

Fix:

```
r[i%100] = i**2 # some function to compute and save
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for? This code will iterate from 0 to 2000 in intervals of 100, mapping some function (`x -> x**2`) over each interval, calculating the mean and printing the result.

```
import numpy as np

r = np.zeros(10000)
for i in range(0, 2000, 100):
    interval = [x ** 2 for x in r[i:i + 100]]
    av_r = np.mean(interval)
    print(av_r)
```

The output from this is just a series of 20 `0.0`.

Comment: `np.zeros(10000)` isn't that excessive ? :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I just copied it from OP's question.

Comment: @Tagc I maybe misunderstand your answer, why the output is twenty `0.0` ? The average of x**2 over an interval should be every time different larger then  `0.0` .

Comment: @PanichiPattumerosPapaCastoro Every element of `r` is 0. Therefore every element of every possible interval or `r` will be 0. 0 squared is 0. The mean of an array containing only 0's is 0. Therefore the mean of every possible interval of `r` is 0.

Comment: @PanichiPattumerosPapaCastoro I think I'm confused on what you're trying to accomplish. I assumed `r` being an array of zeros was a placeholder for `r` containing a set of real data, of which you wanted to square each element. You actually want to square each value `i` in the range 0-2000 instead, and calculate the means of intervals of that?